# Change UIActionSheet buttons background color and button font

Tags: ios8, uiactionsheet, uialertcontroller

I have a UIActionSheet in my application. I want to change the background color of actionsheet buttons and the font of the buttons. I made a search found below code:

```
for (UIView *_currentView in actionSheet.subviews)
        {
            if ([_currentView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
            {
               //DO YOUR WORK
            }
        }
```

but this code is not working on ios 8. for ios I found below code too:

```
 [[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIAlertController class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

but this code only changes the button's font color.

Is there a way for changing the button's background color too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you are trying to do is something you should not do and should never have been doing. UIActionSheet and UIAlertController provide *standard* views with a very small number of variants and a completely standard appearance. You should not attempt to mess with that.

However, don't give up hope! Nothing stops you from devising your *own* view that looks however you want. And on iOS 8 (and iOS 7) this is very easy, because you are allowed to make a presented view controller whose view slides onto the screen and covers it only partially, just like an alert sheet. So go ahead and create your own non-standard column of buttons, rather than trying to modify Apple's standard.

Comment: may you please more especify how can I do this: " make a presented view controller whose view slides onto the screen and covers it only partially, just like an alert sheet. "

Comment: It's particularly easy in iOS 8, because when you do a presented view controller, you are allowed to specify the final size/position of the view, the animation by which it appears and disappears, and whether any "dimming" view should appear behind it. I demonstrate here: https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7/blob/master/CustomAlertViewDemo/CustomAlertViewTransitioner.swift That is for a custom alert view, not an action sheet, but modifying the example to be like an action sheet would be very simple.

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is this:

```
UICollectionViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor() // or any other color you want
```

Note that this affects the background when presented in a popover or on the iPhone. If you are using `UICollectionView`s elsewhere in your app, set the background color manually to override.