# How to change UIAction sheet Cancel button background color

Tags: iphone, swift3.2

I was trying to change the background color of UIAction sheet "Cancel" button but it doesn't work.
Here is my code snippet

```
if let subview = alertController.view.subviews.first, let alertContentView = subview.subviews.first {
    for innerView in alertContentView.subviews {
        innerView.backgroundColor =  UIColor.red//StyleKit.popoverDefaultBackgroundColor
        //drop shadow
        innerView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        innerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
    }
}
let subview = alertController.view.subviews.last! as UIView
let alertContentView = subview.subviews.last! as UIView
alertContentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel".localize(), style: .cancel)

alertController.addAction(changeAction)
alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
```

Comment: First refer below link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287400/change-uiactionsheet-buttons-background-color-and-button-font

Answer (score 0):

Try this - 
`let subView = alertController.view.subviews.first!
 Var alertContentView = subView.subviews.first!
  alertContentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
 alertContentView.layer.cornerRadius = 5`